# How to check view rendered after get data from API Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing, reactive-programming

I have a problem with getting data from the API using VUE JS and then I want to print this page. After I got data from API, Elements did not completely render and the print option popped up with the blank data in the page. It worked with the setTimeout function, but it did not work perfectly with all my clients. If I want to work perfectly with all my clients I will set a long waiting timeout. It is a bad solution.

```
methods: {
            getData() {
                axios.get('/api/sale/receipt/' + this.$route.params.uuid).then((res) => {
                    this.sale = res.data
                    if(this.sale.customer == null) {
                        this.sale.customer = {}
                    }
                    
                    $('.main-loader').hide();
                    // setTimeout(function() {
                        window.print();
                        window.close();
                    // }, 2000);
                }).catch((res) => {

                });
            }
        },
```

So after the elements rednerd print options will popup. Thanks

Comment: Check the [lifehooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) of Vue. Also, where are you calling thing `getData()` method?

Comment: Yes, I call it in created()

Comment: I think also using `nextTick()` will help you to start printing when the data is loaded and updated by Vue.

Comment: After I add `await nextTick()` the `window.print()` is not running. Now I found the solution on my question. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using [$nextTick()](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#nexttick) in Vue.

If you use `window.print()` directly, without `$nextTick()` then you will not get the list of posts in your print, since it takes time to update the DOM.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue 

const App = {
  data() {
    return { 
      posts: [] 
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((data) => 
              {
                this.posts = data;
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                  window.print();
                });
              });
      }   
  }  
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <label>Id:</label>{{post.id}}<br/>
  <label>Title:</label>{{post.title}}<br/>
  <label>Body:</label>{{post.body}}<br/>
  <hr/>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I fount answer on my question.

```
methods: {
            async getData() {
                await axios.get('/api/sale/receipt/' + this.$route.params.uuid).then((res) => {
                    this.sale = res.data
                    if(this.sale.customer == null) {
                        this.sale.customer = {}
                    }
                    $('.main-loader').hide();
                    // setTimeout(function() {
                        // window.print();
                        // window.close();
                    // }, 2000);
                }).catch((res) => {

                });

                window.print();
                window.close();
            }
        },
```

I just add `async getData()` to my function and add `await` to `axios`. And then move the `window.print()` outside of the `axios`. Now it works.